# How to run locally installed node packages on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, powershell, npm

I'm not able to run locally installed packages on windows with 
Node v12.16.1
NPM v6.13.4

The project i'm working on makes use of vue which requires various dev dependencies (@vue/cli-service, @vue/cli-plugin-babel, ...). On a unix machine running the command `npm start` will simply take the executables used in the start script from the local node_modules folder. Windows somehow only makes use of the globally installed packages.

- Installing every dev dependency globally is not a viable solution.
- I also don't want to make use of npx because the setup works well on any other os.

I've tried to add `.\node_modules\.bin` to the windows path variable, but without success.

There must be another to run local packages on windows, right?

Comment: How about `node start` ?

Comment: Whats the difference between `node start` and `npm start`? I couldn't find a documentation about it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok .. that is a bit weird. The repository was cloned to a drive other then `C:\`. When I moved everything to `C:\` all commands executed fine.

I'll try to investigate this issue further. If I find a better explaination I'll post it here